# Why the entry file for uboot is written in assembly?

Tags: c, u-boot

Why entry point (Start.S) of uboot is written in assembly? Is it for performance reason or there are other issues. why it is not written in C?

Comment: Probably because it does stuff that can't be expressed in C.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the entry point is guaranteed an initial state that fits the form of a C function call in the ABI the C compiler uses, C cannot express an entry point. If there is any relevant state in registers, this would be (1) potentially-clobbered by any prologue code the compiler generates, for call-clobbered registers, and (2) even if the registers are call-saved, the compiler might move them somewhere not exposed to the C code, even if the C code has access to inline assembly extensions. (A side note: uClibc's `setjmp` implementation for some archs is buggy in this regard; it is wrongly written with inline asm, rather than an asm function, and assumes that the compiler has not modified/moved call-saved registers already when the inline asm is reached.) Many entry points (e.g. for ELF binaries) also have initial state positioned on the stack in ways that are not representable from C.

Answer (score 0):

Each Processor architecture has its own startup sequence and procedure.
They can be too specific, to be generalized under C.

For example

ARM requires that startup and initialization of a kernel be done in supervisor mode, which is enabled by setting the S bit in the control register. And then switch the control to user mode. This procedure varies in x86 and PowerPC.

Yes it can be done in C, but it makes more sense to perform architecture related initialization, in architecture specific assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

The entry point is in assembly because during the early boot phase there is NO facility to call C functions. Before we can call a C function the system should already have a valid stack. The valid stack could be in DDR RAM or in SRAM. Before we use DDR RAM or SRAM we must initialize it first. Before initializing these, we must set the PLLs and other clocks first. You should see a pattern here. Everything starts at the reset vector (well unless the u-boot is a RAMBOOT variant).

All of this early low-level initialization is performed by the start up code (in assembly). After the memory is initialized, the code sets up the stack and heap, and continues running the C-coded part.